The topological entropy of potential space filling curves on the unit interval
By a potential space  filling  curve we  mean a  continuous  function $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$  such that there is a  continuous surgective  function $g:[0,1]\to [0,1]^2$ with $f=\pi_1 \circ g$ where $\pi_1$ is the projection on the  first coordinate.
I  am  curious about the  topological entropy of a typical potential space  filling  curve $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$.

Are there both examples of  vanishing and  non vanishing of  such potential filling curve?


Is there a map that you are considering applying?

@AnthonyQuas  Thank  you for  your comment. In fact  by this  post I  am curious about the diversity of space  filling  curve from the entropy point of view. What quantities can be realized as the  entropy of some potential filling curve? Can one say that the  entropy is  always  non zero?

I guess my comment is that I only know how to define entropy when there is a dynamical system. In your question, you have a space, but I don’t see the dynamics.

@AnthonyQuas  I think topologicql entropy is defined for non injective maps too. Here $f$ is a map on the interval which is composition of the projection $\pi_2$ with a space filling curve. so we have a dynamic on the interval

@AnthonyQuas is injectivity of f the point you are indicating to?or you meqn consideration of a precise example of $f$?

OK. I understand the question now. I thought you were asking about the richness of the collection of all space-filling curves. But it now sounds as though you are talking about the dynamical properties (the first coordinate of) one space filling curve.
